# WooCommerce allow customer to add another customer

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have an idea in mind but not any code to implement. I want is that, how can a customer add another customer from his/her dashboard.

I would like it to implement into woocommerce to make it invite only platform. When the customer signs up after that he can invite two users then only those next two users can purchase.

Comment: check it https://wordpress.org/plugins/refer-a-friend-for-woocommerce-by-wpgens/

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/